ag-grid: api.updateGridOptions is not a function
I am banging my head on this:
I have an ag-grid react component, for which i am trying to to update the grid options after initialization.
so in the onGridReady event, I am accessing the api (params.api), but the updateGridOptions method, described in the documentation does not exist in the returned api object, it just isn't there.
I have no idea even where to start looking for a solution
here is the code:
onGridReady = params => {
        this.gridApi = params.api
        this.updateFunc = params.api.updateGridOptions;
    };

and here is (a screenshot from) the gridApi object I'm getting from my debugger:

as you can see, there is no trace of the update function that supposed to be there (along with any other api function, frankly).
something most be wrongly configured or constructed here.

I'm not sure what event to use but perhaps gridReady is too early? updateGridOptions: Function - Updates the provided subset of gridOptions with the provided values. (Cannot be used on Initial properties.) https://www.ag-grid.com/javascript-data-grid/grid-api/#reference-gridOptions-updateGridOptions
